# C++ Char array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

So I have char array and in each index of array I have a piece of picture that I need to write in console. In one function I have array and in other function I have the output. The problem is that in output I only get first element, I also tried without [i], with & or *. But nothing worked corectly.

[image: Code]

Comment: please paste your code into the question rather than an image

Comment: so is this c++ or c#? half c++ half c#? c+#?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That last comment of yours made my day!

Comment: "So I have char array..." No, you have an array of `char*`. The two are vastly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call should be

```
output(array, max);
```

instead of

```
output(*array,max);
```

which uses an unintended dereferencing of `array`.

Comment: The `output` should be declared differently, too.

Comment: Yes, but how? I'm not deeply involved in C++ currently. The intention is to declare an array of strings; how should it be done? As `char** array` ?